# Javascript code is not working second time

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am newbie in javascript. I have two textboxes

`<asp:TextBox id="txtbox1" class="txt" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="txtbox2" class="txt" runat="server" />`

I am using javascript validation here so that user can't enter NULL value. My javascript code is fine. On button I am using this code.

`<asp:Button ID="btn_add" runat="server" OnClientClick="return validate();" OnClick="btn_add_Click" Text="Submit" />`

Now, the problem is that when user leaves textbox blank and click on button, error message is shown and after that user corrects his mistakes and again click on the button then button is not working. Nothing happens.

Edit: My javascript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        var error = 0,value,a,q,i;
        value = document.getElementsByClassName("txt");

        for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
        {
            if (value[i].textContent == '')
            {
                document.getElementById("errmsg").innerHTML = "TextBox can't be blank";

                error = 1;
                break;
            }
        }


       if (error == 0)
        { return true }
        else { return false}

    }

</script>`
```

Comment: Please post more code. Specifically, what is your validate() function doing? Also, what browser are you using? I think Chrome no longer supports inline javascript.

Comment: What *is* supposed to happen when u click the button? Can u put a breakpoint inside of "btn_add_Click" to verify that execution gets there?

Comment: @ChrisFremgen Check my edit and I am using chrome but javascript runs fine for first time when textbox is null.

Comment: Why don't you use a couple of [RequiredFieldValidators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter There is some server side code is also execute on button click. Can you more elaborate your point.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, I am not much familiar with script errors. I am new to javascript.

Comment: I am not sure about this. After searching I thought this is a postback problem. Am I correct?

Comment: @DavidSherret RequiredFieldValidators are server side code. I want validate textboxes on client side.

Comment: You might want to check your server side code rather concentrating on client side JS code; cause to me it looks like JS is doing just fine.

Comment: @Viktor I use them for client-side and server-side validation all the time. Maybe there's a configuration or property setting that needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thrown by your error variable, I would have expected that to fail. The fix is pretty simple. You are using an input and textContent is not a valid attribute as the text is not nested inside the tag (unlike div, p, textarea etc.).

Inputs contain their content in attributes, when a user modifies an input the value is changed and there is the clue. You must access the inputs value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
    var error = 0,value,a,q,i;
    value = document.getElementsByClassName("txt");

    for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
    {
        if (value[i].value == '')
        {
            document.getElementById("errmsg").innerHTML = "TextBox can't be blank";

            error = 1;
            break;
        }
    }


   if (error == 0)
    { return true }
    else { return false}

}
</script>`

<form action="form_action.php" method="get">
  <div id="errmsg"></div>
  <div>
    <label>First name</label>
    <input class="txt" type="text" name="fname" value="" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="return validate()" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

If you were to bring this piece of code on a bit I would opt for not using the inline function assignment and as mentioned in other comments, use a required flag, then on DOMready check the form for required fields.

Then you can deal with them as you wish, onSubmit, onChange. It will provide you with a bit more flexibility.

ps. You have got to tell me what this does... `var error = 1,value,a,q,i`

Comment: I checked condition `if (error == 0)
    { return true }
    else { return false}`. `error` has a default value `0` if the validation code executes then value of it will be `1`. Elements by class name is stored in `value`. `a` & `i` are for loops

Comment: So you're declaring our variables, I missed that. It Just looks a little strange. I would ave probably opted to declare them all first `var error, value, a, q, i` Then set each one on a new line just for readability. `error = 1;` etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I soved this when user moved out of text box.I through the error.

```
<form name="forms.sample" novalidate>

    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input ng-focus="focus=true" ng-blur="focus=false" style="width:400px;" class="form-control" name="Name" type="text" data-ng-model="Name" ng-pattern="SomePattern" required placeholder="enter the Name here" />
        <div ng-messages for="forms.sample.Name.$error" ng-if="!focus">
            <div ng-if='forms.sample.Name.$touched' ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            <div ng-if='forms.sample.Name.$touched' ng-message="pattern">Enter a valid domain name</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>    
</form>
```